# Is it possible to try Esri Developer Network (EDN) without purchasing license?

Tags: license, arcgis-platform, edn

Albeit using QGIS for most of my GIS tasks, I still use ArcMap for final map production. I am curious and would like to test out EDN. According to Esri the annual subscription is $1,500. I'm not sure I'm ready to invest that much money into it as I'm not sure I'll even use it.

Do I have any options to develop on the ArcGIS platform without subscribing to EDN?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call your local office and ask for a trial.

http://www.esri.com/about-esri/locations.html

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I just sent them an email and we will see. On a further note, I haven't checked your blog in a while, thanks for answering and reminding me of its awesomeness

Answer (score 2):

If you just need ArcMap and not the Developer tools, just get ArcGIS Desktop Standard for home use.  It's $100.  This comes with ArcPy and obviously, because of this, the GAC libraries, so you could develop using it.

If you need the Server and all of the ArcObjects, ArcIMS, ArcSDE, etc, etc, etc, then I'd advise speaking to the local agent, and asking for a trial, which I am sure they could give.

Comment: I'm pretty sure using ArcGIS Desktop Standard for home use that way is not allowed.  Check the license.

Comment: It isn't, unless they are for your own use.  That's a fairly liberal interpretation mind...